# Cannot GET /users Using Express Router

Tags: express

I"m using express router. It keep on showing Cannot GET /users. I'm following a tutorial he did the same thing. The users.js file is in router folder.

**Server.js**

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Hi")
    res.render('index', { text: "Hey" })
})

const userRouter = require("./routes/users")
app.use = ('/users', userRouter)

app.listen(3000)
```

**users.js**

```
const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router()

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("User List")
})

router.get('/new', (req, res) => {
    res.send("New User List")
})


module.exports = router
```

Comment: can you upodate your server.js like this -> `const userRouter = require("./routes/users")
app.use ('/users', userRouter)

app.listen(3000)`

Comment: Thankyou. It worked. It was mistake on my side.

Comment: i will add it as an answer so that it helps others in the future, you can accept/upvote it :)

Answer (score 1):

Just update your server.js like this

```
const userRouter = require("./routes/users") 
app.use ('/users', userRouter)  
app.listen(3000)
```

Remeber `The .use() method in express is a *middleware handler. An Express application is essentially a series of middleware function calls.`